# Как побайтно собрать строку на Arduino

Tags: строки, arduino, bluetooth

По bluetooth с одной ардуино на другую передается строка. Вторая ардуинка побайтно принимает эту строку и в сериал порт так же побайтно ее отправляет. Выходит по одному-два символа на строчке. Как полностью собрать строку, чтобы далее выполнять с ней какие-то действия? В передаваемой строке делал указатели конца строки, в данном случае оставил `"\n"`. Пробовал такой вариант, но на выходе получаю все равно какую-то ерунду и не всегда мой "флажок" замечается, вроде по нему должно триггериться, но иногда проскакивает в мониторе порта, когда смотрю

```
char buffer[100];
int i;
for(i=0;i<100;i++)
{
buffer[i]=Serial.Read();
Serial.flush();
if(buffer[i]=='\n')
break;
}
```

Comment: `Serial.flush()` — почти наверняка лишнее... если `Serial.Read()` читает один байт с синезубого uart'а, то в остальном тут всё в порядке... из распространённых граблей, могу предположить, что после цикла в строку завершающий ноль не добавляется...

Comment: @Fat-Zer почему этот ноль не добавляться может? я пробовал через "\0" делать, но строка все равно не собирается, так же побайтно выводит, а не целым значением

Comment: не добавляться может только потому что ты в коде его забыл добавить... в приведённом отрывке на мой взгляд ошибок нет, окромя пары подозрительных моментом (`flush` не нужный и того что Read с большой буквы написан)... возможно что-то не так с передачей или с приёмом дальше по коду...